# Ubuntu: How to move windows in batch from one display to another?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, vnc, window-manager

I have several program windows open on my main display (showing on my physical screen).

I've created a second display for VNC connections (using `vncserver :14`).

Is there a way I can move all open windows from the default display to the VNC display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I use Compiz's [Window Grouping](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Group) for stuff like this.

Comment: After I group them, how do I move them to the other display?

Comment: If there's not a shortcut you know, I believe that dragging one will move them all IIRC.